# Nested Variables in Unity Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make nested variables inside the unity inspector with a script, kind of like this:

[image: example showing a "nested variable" in the unity inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Doing so does require knowledge of `UnityEditor` and not only (as you say ... nested variables) can give you many other control options in the inspector. To do this, I created a sample code called `MenuManager`. As you can see this code:

```
public class MenuManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool variable1;

    public float nestedVariable;
    
    //...
}
```

Unity itself does not provide any attributes such as `[Range]` or `[Header]` for such a request, and to do this you need to define a `CustomEditor` for the class but Before to do that, you need to create a folder similar to the photo with name of `Editor` and put it in the Assets folder. Then create another script with name of `MenuEditor` (for example here ..) and put it in a Editor folder.

[image]

Now open the `MenuEditor` code. Inherit it from the `Editor` class. Editor class is base class for editing inspector and more. It will give you many override methods with access to the features inside the unity editor. and make sure it has two Attributes [Custom Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) as well as [CanEditMultipleObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanEditMultipleObjects.html).

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MenuManager))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class MenuEditor : Editor
{
    //..
}
```

This code gives you access to the `MenuManager` script. According to the following code, I coded a Nested variable to the first one.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MenuManager))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class MenuEditor : Editor 
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var myMenu = target as MenuManager; // target is script reference that we want to manipulate it

        myMenu.variable1 = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Variable 1", myMenu.variable1); // show first variable on inspector

        GUI.enabled = myMenu.variable1; // access to second variable depend of first

        myMenu.nestedVariable =EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Nested Variable", myMenu.nestedVariable);
        
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

After finishing the work, you can access the nested variable only by setting first one to true.

Remember after doing this you can access many other features just inside MenuEditor class but if you find this difficult, I suggest you use [Odin Inspecter](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041). I hope you have reached your answer. comment under answer if you need more information.